# Instantiating IDictionary<K, IEnumerable<V>>

Tags: c#, .net, covariance

I have a method with the signature

```
public void Foo(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> data)
{
}
```

and wish to pass in

```
private Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> myInput = 
    new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>()
{
};
```

The line

```
Foo(myInput);
```

yields the compiler error:

> Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>`

`Dictionary<K,V>` implements `IDictionary<K,V>` and `HashSet<T>`  implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

- Why is the compiler unable to perform the conversion?
- How can I create an instance of data that I can pass to `Foo`?

NOTE

If I change the signature to

```
public void Foo(IDictionary<string, HashSet<string>> data)
```

the compilation succeeds.  However, I do not need any knowledge that a concrete type such as `HashSet<T>` is being passed in.  Any `IEnumerable<T>` will do.

**UPDATE**

The following compiles:

```
public void Foo(IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> data)
{
    List<string> item = new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
    data.Add("key", item);
    HashSet<string> item2 = new HashSet<string>() { "quu" };
    data.Add("key2", item2);
}
```

so clearly `data` can accept mixed-type values that all implement `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Comment: @poke: I have read that before but don't understand how it applies in this situation.  The answer is probably lurking there somewhere (question is tagged covariance).

Comment: The problem here is with the `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface. Neither of its type parameters are covariant. So that keeps anything that's not exactly of that type from being assigned. Period.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why this isn’t work is because of restrictions about [covariance and contravariance in generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). The best way to explain this is to show an example of why this *has to fail*.

Assuming `Foo` has a valid signature, the type system promises that the following works:

```
var myInput = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

// assuming a valid signature for `Foo`
Foo(myInput);

// according to the type of `myInput` the following MUST work
HashSet<string> item = myInput["foo"];
item.Add("baz");
```

That is what *absolutely* has to work. So anything `Foo` does has to make sure that this still works.

So ignoring above for a moment, let’s assume the following *valid* implemention for `Foo`:

```
public void Foo (IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> data)
{
    List<string> item = new List<string>(){ "foo", "bar" };
    data.Add("foo", item);
}
```

Because [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) implements `IEnumerable<string>`, adding a list object to the dictionary that stores `IEnumerable<string>`s absolutely works. Again: Above is a valid implementation of `Foo` for its signature.

However, if we now combine both code segments, it falls apart: The object stored at key `"foo"` is not a `HashSet<string>` but a `List<string>`. So the assignment at `HashSet<string> item = myInput["foo"]` would fail. But here is a conflict! The type system should ensure that the assignment works no matter what happens inside `Foo`; but the implementation of `Foo` is also completely valid for its signature.

So instead of making some arbitrary and intransparent rules here, this is simply not allowed. The type system just prevents such calls of `Foo` with an incompatible parameter. And no, because IDictionary is invariant, it isn’t possible to work around this restriction.

Comment: OK, so part 2 - how can I instantiate data that I can pass to `Foo`?  Or is that principally impossible?

Comment: Have a look at my edit.  It turns out, you can add both a `List<string>` and a `HashSet<string>` to `IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> data`

Comment: Yes, the implementation of `Foo` isn’t the problem. My implementation above *is* valid, just like your implementation in your question is. But passing a more specific type to the function will fail because its original type cannot be enforced any longer (see my edit for an example).

Comment: Regarding you edit `Because then something like this would be the case` - I don't see that.  `data`'s values only implement `IEnumerable<string>`.  You would have to attempt to cast to `HashSet<string>` in `HashSet<string> item = myInput["key"];`.  The cast would fail for the `List<string>`.

Comment: But the type system promises me that it works. If I have a dictionary that stores hash sets, and *anything* happens to the dictionary (inside `Foo`), then I can still get items from it which are of type `HashSet`. That’s irrelevant of what happens inside Foo.

Comment: Why does the type system promise that you can assign `IEnumerable<T>` to `HashSet<T>`?  That seemscore to your argument.

Comment: It doesn’t; that’s the point. The type system promises me that for a `Dictionary<S, HashSet<T>>`, when I get an item out of it, that item is of type `HashSet<T>`. So *if* I were to add an `IEnumerable<T>` to the dictionary instead, then that promise couldn’t be guaranteed anymore—which is why the whole thing fails.

Comment: Ah I see now.  The problem is that you use the `IEnumerable<T>` interface to add something that is not what the real type is.  Must have been too tired yesterday :-)

Answer (score 1):

@poke's answer gives you the why, so I won't spend much time on that.

You can manage this restriction by using a generic method with a `where` restriction like this:

```
public void Foo<T>(IDictionary<string, T> data)
    where T : IEnumerable<string>
{
}
```

Now your `Foo` method accepts any type of object that implements `IEnumerable<string>`, regardless of the solid type of the enumerable.  You can do anything you like to the dictionary apart from add items with content.

But let's say that you *do* want to add some items:

```
public void Foo<T>(IDictionary<string, T> data)
    where T : ICollection<string>, new()
{
    var col = new T();
    col.Add("bar");

    data["col"] = col;
}
```

Here's a quick test:

```
var a = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
var b = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var c = new Dictionary<string, LinkedList<string>>();

Foo(a);
Foo(b);
Foo(c);
```

Compiles and runs fine.  All three dictionaries end up with a new collection of the appropriate solid type containing the string `bar`.

What you can't do is add a collection of the wrong type to the `Dictionary`.  Ever.  Whatever operation you try to perform on the object must be consistent with the solid type of that object.  Which is why the `Foo` method needs to be generic in this case.

Comment: Certainly answers Part 2 of the question.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, here's the way to make your call work with a little help from LINQ:

```
Foo(myInput.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.AsEnumerable()));
```

Comment: While this allows you to call `Foo` with the contents of `myInput` transformed to an appropriate format, the desired side-effects of `Foo` will now operate on the temporary `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` instead of on `myInput` itself.